# Spring security logout over https not working

Tags: jboss, spring-security

I have basic configuration for Spring SEcurity. The logout button works perfectly fine over HTTP but problem appears when dealing with HTTPS. My security config looks like this:

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint"
      access-denied-page="/accessDenied">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('AA_ACCESS')" requires-channel="any"/>
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="siteminderFilter"/>
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/sessionExpired"/>
    </session-management>
    <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
</http>
```

The logout button:

```
<a href="<c:url value="${requestScope.pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout" />">Logout</a>
```

As I said, everything works fine over HTTP, but not HTTPS.

I get error 404 Page not found. Ports the app is running is: 11501 for JBoss AS, while HTTPS is Apache with ajp connector to JBoss, apache is 16000, ajp 8009.

Comment: It's unlikely to be a Spring Security issue. More likely something to do with proxying/redirects etc. Please check the debug logs and provide some more information. What is the exact request which causes the 404? How does it appear in the JBoss/tomcat access log?

Comment: The request that fails is logout. After pressing logout button, over HTTP my cookie is cleaned while over HTTPS I have 404 error. After checking both Apache and JBoss logs, I found that over HTTPS, to logout url there's added a slash so url looks like this : `webcontext//j_spring_security_logout` is it the cause? Why this slash is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luke Taylor was right. It's not Spring Secuiry issue. Remember kids, check everything twice after your colleagues. In my case, Apache VirtualHost was wrongly configured:

```
<VirtualHost *:11600>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/apache/htdocs/aa"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/apache/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/apache/conf/server.key"
    ProxyPass /admin ajp://localhost:8009/admin/ <--- HERE
    <Directory "/apache/htdocs/aa">
      DirectoryIndex index.html
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice additional slash at the end of ProxyPass, that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it works on http so i dont know if this will help but you can try to set the `logout-success-url` on the logout configuration, in case that the 404 error is due to a missing page where you are redirected after the logout is complete.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-logout

Comment: Check my comment above. Unfotunatelly, its not problem with success-url bo logout url itself :(